# jQuery use contex menu on table

Tags: jquery, datatables

i'm using datatables and for any action on that i want to have contex menu with `on()` function. i can use `.live()` function but this method for upgrade to new version of jquery and using `.on()` below code does not work, how can help me for change that?

jquery LIVE function (no problem for using that):

```
$('#showCategories tbody tr').live('contextmenu', function (event) {
    var nTds_showCategories = $('td', this);
    $(oTable_categories.fnSettings().aoData).each(function (){$(this.nTr).removeClass('row_selected');});
    $(event.target.parentNode).addClass('row_selected');
    $('.showCategoriesMenus').css({'top' : event.pageY ,'left' : event.pageX-150});
    $('.showCategoriesMenus').show();
    iId_categories = $(nTds_showCategories[0]).text() ;
    event.returnValue= false;
    return false;
});
```

this method not work:

```
$("#showCategories").on('contextmenu', '#showCategories tbody tr', function(event){
    var nTds_showCategories = $('td', this);
    $(oTable_categories.fnSettings().aoData).each(function (){$(this.nTr).removeClass('row_selected');});
    $(event.target.parentNode).addClass('row_selected');
    $('.showCategoriesMenus').css({'top' : event.pageY ,'left' : event.pageX-150});
    $('.showCategoriesMenus').show();
    iId_categories = $(nTds_showCategories[0]).text() ;
    event.returnValue= false;
    return false;
});
```

HTML/PHP:

i'm using `display` class for all datatables

```
echo"
<div id='pane_category' class='scroll-pane' style='height: 364px;'>
    <ul class='styledlist' >
        <table cellpading=0 cellspacing=0 class='display' id='showCategories'>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th style='width:5%;height:12px!important;'>".$popular_messages['id']."</th>
                    <th style='width:95%;'>".$admin_contents['title']."</th>
                </tr>
            <thead>
            <tbody style='line-height:25px;'>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    <ul>
</div>";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `#showCategories` on second parameter.. It should be like this:

```
$("#showCategories").on('contextmenu', 'tbody tr', function(event){
    ....
});
```

Comment: @Nix R. Eyes, how to change `$('#cancel_save_category').live('click',function(){` to use .on()?

Comment: if `#cancel_save_category` is on `#showCategories`'s rows. have it this way and use `class` not `id` for `'cancel_save_category'`: $('#showCategories').on('click','.cancel_save_category',function(){...}); To help you with `.on()`, read more here: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Because you can't have multiple elements with the same id. And i guess you will have more than 1 row in your table.